# Promise rejection when I try to load fonts in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I get a problem with Expo and react-native. When I try to *loadAsync* font from assets folder I get this error:

> [Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: Font not found /data/data/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/.../ExponentAsset-5868d2d7f28da04ee373451e87d682f8.ttf]

My code in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { configureStore } from "./store.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { AppLoading, Font } from 'expo';
import MainWrapper from './components/mainWrapper'

const store = configureStore();

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    appReady: false
  }
  loadAssets = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Arial': require('./assets/fonts/Arial.ttf')
    });
    this.setState({appReady: true});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAssets()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {this.state.appReady ?
          <MainWrapper />
        :
          <AppLoading />
        }
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

and I use

```
"expo": {
  "sdkVersion": "21.0.0"
}
```

Most of my App.js I took from Expo example with some changes. Do you have any ideas how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What does your imports look like?

Comment: @bennygenel I updated my question with imports. When I tried to use *FontAwesome* from '@expo/vector-icons' instead of Arial.ttf I got error **TypeError: asset.downloadAsync is not a function**

Answer (score 1):

It was broken *.ttf* file. I downloaded correct file of font from another source and my problem has been resolved. But what about FontAwesome I will explore this.